# how does google update their search indexes

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers

If i ask a question on SO, in no time I can search my question title on Google and get my SO question link as the first result.
This question link must have been crawled by their bot.
How come they update their search indexes so fast??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a lot money so they can buy and use thousands computers. They visit popular places more often. And popular places can send links/pages automatically - see [Submit Url](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url)

Comment: does SO submits the url for each question to google?

Comment: ask SO but it can be true. It is natural in SEO/SEM. More urls mean more visitors.More visitors means more clicked ads. And more clicked ads mean more money for SO.